# Error in importing ctypes.wintypes

Tags: python, linux, ctypes

When I tried to import `ctypes.wintypes` am getting this error, how can I fix this?

```
In [2]: import ctypes.wintypes
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-8395760a4e8a> in <module>()
----> 1 import ctypes.wintypes

/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/wintypes.py in <module>()
     21 
     22 from ctypes import _SimpleCData
---> 23 class VARIANT_BOOL(_SimpleCData):
     24     _type_ = "v"
     25     def __repr__(self):

ValueError: _type_ 'v' not supported
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can import `ctypes.wintypes` only in Windows. (`ctypes.wintypes` contains windows specific data types.)

Windows:

```
>>> import ctypes.wintypes
>>>
```

Linux:

```
>>> import ctypes.wintypes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/wintypes.py", line 23, in <module>
    class VARIANT_BOOL(_SimpleCData):
ValueError: _type_ 'v' not supported
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks :) In my c program there is a thread which continously reads the com port how can i access that in python in windows

Comment: @ganeshredcobra, Post a separated question.

Comment: @LucasCimon Please post a separated question.